# A (very sexualized) women controlled world, where the main character joins the resistance

Tags: story-identification

I read maybe a chapter of this online, several years ago. There were **a lot** of sexual elements, it was interestingly bizarre, and satirical.

Women have united and taken over the world. They have a queen. The women go to work. The men are only around for mating, to raise the kids, to do domestic duties, and for a few to be in their "White Knight Guard". And even then recent technology allows females to reproduce without men.

The main character (male) stumbles into the underground resistance with a very 'manly' leader. They decide to infiltrate a facility (not sure where) using a 'Trojan dildo'. They inadvertently find that it can vibrate and it gets them found out. They are then surrounded by 'White Knights' who I believe capture them and take them before their queen.

The fine details are a bit hazy, but if you've read it you probably remember it.

Comment: "They decide to infiltrate a facility (not sure where) using a **'trojan dildo'**. **They inadvertently find that it can vibrate** and it gets them found out. ", should have seen that coming

Comment: Please tell me that you want to find this book again so that you can burn it.

Comment: @Aegon no pun intended, I presume ;)

Comment: Does the story happen in the hell?

Comment: Not gonna lie I would read this book.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"[The Red Pill Movement](https://amp.reddit.com/r/TheBluePill/comments/1rhm43/the_red_pill_movement_in_2050/)" as found in Reddit.

> The Red Pill Movement, in 2050. A 5-part series on the Red Piller's dystopian fantasies. Feminism has won and the matriarchs have enslaved the men. Y Chromosomes have been banned and the male gender is being slowly wiped out. But deep in the shadows, when the matriarchs are too busy painting their nails, a group of men are beginning to mobilise. The mysterious Red Pill Movement is their only hope of taking down the regime and winning back the sex that they deserve.

Mention of the [Trojan Dildo](https://amp.reddit.com/r/TheBluePill/comments/1rn0vn/the_red_pill_movement_in_2050_day_3_the_trojan/):

> And that's why I involved myself in the Trojan Dildo plan.
>
> The STEM's face was gleaming. He proudly presented us with his newest invention. The Giant Purple Dildo. Taller and bigger than any man in the room, we were all in awe of it. I imagined what it would be like if my penis was that size. How much power I would have.

And the vibration and a mention of the White Knights:

> We heard the woman jump out of her chair, startling us. My foot slipped and hit part of the electronics. Suddenly, the dildo started shaking.
>
> Through the dark, I could see the horror on Alpha 1's face. The STEM had made the Giant Dildo into a Giant Vibrator.
>
> The dildo started shaking faster and faster and the loud buzz increased with intensity. I put my hands against the walls to steady myself and felt the vibrations ripple through my body. Then the whole structure fell over onto its side and I found myself lying on top of Alpha 1 as the dildo rolled around the floor, buzzing intensely, his erect penis jabbing into my leg.
>
> Fearing that I may be seen as a beta, I kicked open the hidden door in the side of the dildo and rolled out. Alpha 1 began to crawl out after me.
>
> The White Knights approach us with their dildo-batons. I pick up the Giant Dildo with my alpha strength and throw it at the White Knights. Our Giant Dildo is no match for their tiny ones.

Comment: Found by searching for *story women rule world "trojan dildo"*

Comment: I was afraid it was gonna be a straight-ahead male fantasy thing but this is pretty great satire

Comment: @Fuzzy I hope you didn't google that at work!

Comment: @Möoz: I was on vacation. ^_^