# Sci-fi short story about a future where women rule the world and men are worker drones who have to earn money to buy their penises

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

On Episode 194 of the *Flophouse* podcast, one of the hosts, Elliott Kalan, asks if any listeners can help identify a short story he remembers, possibly from  *Asimov's*, about a future in which women ruled the world, and men were worker drones who had to earn enough money to purchase a penis.

As none of the listeners wrote in with the answer, does anyone on SciFi SE know what this story is?

Comment: :) My first thought was https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166468/a-very-sexualized-women-controlled-world-where-the-main-character-joins-the-r/166471#166471, but there's no buying of penises.

Answer (score 6):

This makes me think of Neal Barrett's "Hard Times" (Asimovs 2003 https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?101499), in which low level workers (I don't remember the high-ups being women in particular) need to "earn" access to various bodily abilities.  BestSF.net reviewed it http://bestsf.net/asimovs-april-2003/

> As one has come to expect from Barrett, a somewhat off-the-wall and
> entirely bodacious story. Dawkit’s life is about to change, as he is
> to get a special present. A very special present.
>
> After a surgical addition to his body, Dawkit is now equipped for …
> lurve. Actually, let’s not mince words – he was one of the multidude
> of men without dicks. And now he has one. And boy, is he gonna use it.
>
> However, Dawkit does find himself being led by his pecker, and he
> finds himself in a predicament.